# ApachePOI generate excel (Autosize Row) with image using Java

Tags: java, grails, apache-poi

I am trying to create excel file with image in it, using apache poi.  What happening is data which i filled in other cells are not appearing.

**ApachePOIImageDemo.java**

```
public class ApachePOIImageDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("------------ Start Main()-------------!");
        try {

            List<Car> carList = new ArrayList<Car>();

            Car car1 = new Car("white","GJ01OP1324","/home/vivek/1.jpg","White Maruthi 800");
            Car car2 = new Car("Black","GJ01OP1244","/home/vivek/1.jpg","Black Mercedes");
            Car car3 = new Car("Red","GJ01OP244","/home/vivek/1.jpg","Red Toyota Innova");
            Car car4 = new Car("Blue","MH01OP1224","/home/vivek/1.jpg","Blue Renault Datson");

            carList.add(car1);
            carList.add(car2);
            carList.add(car3);
            carList.add(car4);

            Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
            Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("My Sample Excel");
            CreationHelper creationHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();

            int index = 0;
            for (Car carInstance : carList){
                int columnNumber = 0;
                Row row = sheet.createRow(index);

                Cell cell0 = row.createCell(columnNumber++);
                cell0.setCellValue(index);

                Cell cell1 = row.createCell(columnNumber++);
                cell1.setCellValue(carInstance.getCarColor());

                Cell cell2 = row.createCell(columnNumber++);
                cell2.setCellValue(carInstance.getCarPlateNumber());

                InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(carInstance.getCarImage());
                byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
                int pictureIdx = workbook.addPicture(bytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
                inputStream.close();

                Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
                ClientAnchor anchor = creationHelper.createClientAnchor();

                anchor.setCol1(3);
                anchor.setRow1(index);
                anchor.setCol2(4);
                anchor.setRow2(index+1);

                Picture picture = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);

                columnNumber++;

                Cell cell4 = row.createCell(columnNumber++);
                cell4.setCellValue(carInstance.getDescription());
                index++;
            }


            FileOutputStream fileOut = null;
            fileOut = new FileOutputStream("myFile.xlsx");
            workbook.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("------------ End Main() -------------!");
    }
}
```

My Result : 
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Vj9q.png)

I want to set auto height and width of the columns.

My images are of different sizes in practical. So I need to set auto height-width in my file.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can autosize your column, like this :

```
sheet.autoSizeColumn(numberOfYourCOlumnWithImage);
```